# setTimeout keeps firing, how to make it fire only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a simple chat, it works in different browsers but `setTimeout` keeps firing, and I want it to fire only once as it is pointless to keep firing and I believe also it would cause more stress on the server.

This is the function which is called from somewhere else:

```
function chat_load() {
    $.post('chat.php', {stage:'load'}, function(data) {
        $('#window').html(data);
        setTimeout("chat_load();", 1000);

    });
}
```

I tried something like the following but it just keeps on firing. Also, the function is supposed to fire only when a certain button is clicked, which happens only once every so often.

```
var c = 0;
function chat_load() {
    $.post('chat.php', {stage:'load'}, function(data) {
        $('#window').html(data);
        var t = setTimeout("chat_load();", 1000);
        c++;
        if (c == 3) {
            clearTimeout(t);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: look into long-polling for chat applications :)

Comment: Thanks, but I still need this. Any good long-polling tutes?

Comment: This code is designed to always reschedule `setTimeout` when it runs.

Comment: The code is recursive without a termination which is why it keeps firing.

Comment: @Cube32 Since you mentioned long-polling, it got me thinking about `Comet`. Check [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_(programming)). Do you know if any good feasible widely accepted solution for server side push available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
var c = 0, t;
function chat_load() {
    $.post('chat.php', {stage:'load'}, function(data) {
        $('#window').html(data);
        clearTimeout(t);
        t = setTimeout(chat_load, 1000);            
        if (++c === 3) {
            clearTimeout(t);
            c=0;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, with your code it really does execute a certain number of times, though I see now that my little chat doesn't work properly unless the function keeps repeating itself. Guess I have to go learn about long polling. Anyway thanks, it's always good when you notice my question :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change variables in a asynchronous function

`c++;` wont work

maybe you should do this

```
function addCount() {
   c++;
}
```

and change `c++` to `addCount();`

so this

```
var c = 0;

function addCount() {
   c++;
}

function chat_load() {
    $.post('chat.php', {stage:'load'}, function(data) {
        $('#window').html(data);
        var t = setTimeout("chat_load();", 1000);
        addCount();
        if (c == 3) {
            clearTimeout(t);
        }
    });
}
```